# jQuery exceptions to global $.ajaxSetup() possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use the following to catch an unauthorized access and force a login:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function(){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Works great... when accessing resources on my servers (domain), but now I'm attempting to use 3rd party API resources via ajax calls and their 401's are caught by this as well.  So, how might I either:

1. rewrite the above code to only catch 401's from my domain, or
2. make an $.ajax() call with an exception to the above code (use a different error handler)

Thanks much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Through experimentation I discovered the answer.  $.ajaxSetup() basically sets a default for any $.ajax() requests.  However, the global setup can be overridden for a specific request like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function(){
            //this will catch any and all access denied errors
        }
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: someresouceurl,
    statusCode: {
        401: function(){
            //except this one!
        }
    },
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @MrOBrian's answer, in your 401 function, `this` is set to a settings object containing info about the AJAX request.  One of the properties is `url`.  You can read this, and check if it's your URL or not.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function(){
            var url = this.url;
            if(url === myurl){ // check if url is yours
            }
            else{
                // not your URL, do nothing
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery API

`If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as the error callback.`

I would recommend looking into the jqXHR parameter you get and see if you can narrow it down to just your domain, but I don't know enough about that aspect of jQuery to give you exact code.

Comment: In your function, try to `console.log(arguments, this)`.  One one the objects may contain the URL, so you can only run the function on your URLs.